# JavaFX 8 Conditional ScrollBars on shrinkable Pane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, miglayout

I want to "combine" two different behaviors in one of my panes:

0) if containing scene is bigger than a certain maximum Pane will occupy the top-left corner, using its maximum dimensions. This is normal behavior.

1) shrinking Scene Pane adapts shrinking its contents, no scrollbars. This is normal behavior of e.g.: MigPane.

2) if Scene (or containing Pane) shrinks below a certain minimum dimension then contents do not shrink anymore, but scrollbars appear. This is ScrollPane behavior.

I did not find a way to combine behavior (1) and (2).
Using ScrollPane the contained MigPane will not even try to shrink.

Any suggestion?
TiA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting properties `fitToHeight` and `fitToWidth` will do the trick.

Either use:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

or, in fxml:

```
<ScrollPane fitToHeight="TRUE" fitToWidth="TRUE">
```

This way the enclosed `Node` takes charge: *if* it can be resized (it implements `Resizable`) and *until it can* be resized (it reaches its `minHeight` or `minWidth`) it *will* be resized; otherwise normal `ScrollPane` (3) behavior takes over and `ScrollBar`s will appear.